# Which File for /lib/web/legacy-build.min.js

Tags: magento2, frontend

I'm trying to change comment display in admin order page, i found this file /lib/web/legacy-build.min.js to edit the submitAndReloadArea function but the legacy-build.min.js looks like a generated file, can you give me which file should edit?

Comment: If your problem resolved by editing of legacy-build.min.js file. so you just override this file in your theme

Comment: it's using jquery but variable with single letter submitAndReloadArea(e,d), it's like a generated file, can i found the original function file?

Comment: I think it's prototype library, i will try to modify js in another place